# How to set select2 form value based on other select2 forms value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have two select2 forms in my project, I simply want to update the other select based on the value of the first select. I have a default form of 2 selects and with jquery I'm dynamically adding select inputs. I managed to update the value of select forms on my default select2 forms but the one's i'm rendering using jquery doesn't seem to work the same way. Here is my code :

```
var i = 0;
                            let addRow = 100;
                            let x = 1;
                            let y = 0;
                            $("#addDevice").click(function(){
                                ++i;
                               
                                if(x<addRow){
                                    $("#newRow").append('' +
                                '<div class="row" id ="parent">' +
                                    '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">' +
                                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                                            '<label>მოწყობილობის ID</label>' +
                                            '<div class="input-group">' +
                                                '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                                                    '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-hashtag"></i></span>' +
                                                '</div>' +  
                                                `{{ form.render("storageDeviceCode[]", ["class": "form-control select2 code" ]) }}`+
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">' +
                                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                                            '<label>მოწყობილობის სახელი</label>' +
                                            '<div class="input-group">' +
                                                '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                                                    '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-hdd"></i></span>' +
                                                '</div>' +
                                                `{{ form.render("storageDeviceName[]", ["class": "form-control select2 name"]) }}`+
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>'+ 
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">' +
                                        '<div class="form-group">' +
                                            '<label>რაოდენობა</label>' +
                                            '<div class="input-group">'+
                                                '<div class="input-group-prepend">'+
                                                    '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i></span>'+
                                                '</div>'+
                                                `{{ form.render("storageDeviceQuantity[]", ["class": "form-control quantity"]) }}`+
                                            '</div>'+
                                        '</div>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 mt-2 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">' +
                                        '<button id="removeDevice" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt fa-xs"></i> </button>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'
                                   );
                                   x++;
                                   $('.select2').select2();
                                   

                                                                  
}
var code = document.querySelectorAll('.code');

                                // Set their ids
                                for (var i = 0; i < code.length; i++)
                                code[i].id = 'code-' + x;
                                var name = document.querySelectorAll('.name');

                                // Set their ids
                                for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
                                name[i].id = 'name-' + x;
                                var quantity = document.querySelectorAll('.quantity');

                                // Set their ids
                                for (var i = 0; i < quantity.length; i++)
                                quantity[i].id = 'quantity-' + x;

                                var $eventSelectCode = $("#code-2");
                                var $eventSelectName = $("#name-2");
                                $eventSelectCode.on("select2:select", function (e) { 
                                    return $("#name-2").val(e.params.data.id);
                            });
```

This is how I render the select forms, and then setting ids on each of the added inputs and lastly trying to set the value on name-2 form based on code-2 value.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: the code shared has the following problems to begin with: missing closing `});`; missing html expected to work with the given js; missing actual html encoding the select2 dropboxes shown as server side renders `{{ }}`; and the issue described as `but the one's i'm rendering using jquery doesn't seem to work the same way` is not very easy to grasp. If you take more effort sharing a standalone html that will clearly show the scenario and a working js you will more likely receive a valuable help